problem with GO protoc while using make command
I tried to install this
https://github.com/s77rt/rdpcloud
It has requirements such as:
Go
npm
protoc
composer
I installed all the above, but am still facing multiple errors.
Can you give me any advice on this?
/bin/sh: xor: command not found
/bin/sh: xor: command not found
/bin/sh: xor: command not found
/bin/sh: xor: command not found
/bin/sh: xor: command not found
/bin/sh: xor: command not found
go install mvdan.cc/garble@v0.7.2
go install github.com/s77rt/xor/cmd/xor@latest
cd cert && bash gen.sh
Generating a RSA private key
...........................................................................................++++
..................................++++
writing new private key to 'server-key.pem'
-----
rm -rf proto/go && mkdir -p proto/go && touch proto/go/.keep
cd proto/go && go mod init github.com/s77rt/rdpcloud/proto/go
go: creating new go.mod: module github.com/s77rt/rdpcloud/proto/go
protoc --proto_path=proto/proto --go_out=proto/go --go_opt=paths=source_relative --go-grpc_out=proto/go --go-grpc_opt=paths=source_relative proto/proto/*/*/*.proto
google/protobuf/timestamp.proto: File not found.
models/msi/product.proto: Import "google/protobuf/timestamp.proto" was not found or had errors.
models/msi/product.proto:14:9: "google.protobuf.Timestamp" is not defined.
make: *** [Makefile:55: gen-go] Error 1

